# does WD My Cloud work like dropbox?

Tags: cloud-storage

Does WD My Cloud work like dropbox? I would like to sync a folder in real time between different computers. I thought if WD My Cloud works like dropbox, then it would be cheaper to buy it rather than using dropbox, googl drive, or onedrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WD My Cloud devices are NAS solutions for file sharing withing a network and over the Internet.

NAS devices act as network folders that can be accessed from any device connected to the specific network and, with the proper settings, can be accessed over the Internet, just like the online cloud services you mentioned. A NAS is basically pretty much any storage device connected to a network through a router that can be accessed over that network from another device. A simple example would be a basic external storage drive or a thumb drive connected to your router's USB port that can be accessed through your phone for data transfer from and to it over the internal Wi-Fi.

WD My Cloud devices offer a bit more features such as torrent clients, media serving and other features as well as scheduled or continuous backup solutions.

In your case you can have a folder on the My Cloud device and have access to it from multiple devices either from the WD My Cloud application or from other applications (depending on your preference or need).

Answer (score 1):

### yes.

Pretty much. For your purposes anyway. I think of it as a secondary iCloud. There are some slight differences in terms of niche features, but the core product is essentially the same as most client-server cloud storage and synchronization services.

### but..

The main difference is that Dropbox is marketed as more of an offsite remote file-storage directory, like an online USB thumb-drive for sharing certain files between several devices. Whereas the Western Digital services GUI is more suggestive of an automated full system backup solution for the prevention of data-loss in the event of a catastrophic system failure. However, their actual functionality's remain largely indifferent.

### also;

- [NAS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/network-attached_storage/) (Network Attached Storage).
- [rSync](https://rsync.samba.org/) (Remote Sync). `rsync`.
- [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) (Web Get). `wget`.
- [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) (URL Client). `curl`.
- [SCP](https://www.openssh.com/) (Secure Copy Protocol). `scp`.

Answer (score 1):

My Cloud is nothing like Dropbox for files or videos.

In DropBox you can use Window Explorer and its just like another drive.  You can scroll through photos quickly.

My Cloud you have to open each file individually and its not like having a useable everyday drive on your computer.

This is the most important feature for the average users.

**Here is the relevant info:**

[WD MY Cloud](http://mycloud.com/)

Excerpt:

> My Cloud is a private personal storage unit that plugs into your home network. It automatically backs up and centralizes all your content in one safe place no one can see but you.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 0):

> Does WD My Cloud work like dropbox?

What "works like" means for you? It's like "does a Tesla works like a train?" - yes, both have wheels and electric engines; but there are still differences...

So, both are backup solutions, but there are quite big differences:

### Cloud providers (like dropbox)

pro:

- your data is automatically synchronized
- don't need to maintain devices
- data is stored in multiple locations (protected from hardware failure / disasters...)
- data is available from everywhere

con:

- you don't "own" the device

### Personal hard-drive

pro:

- you "own" the hardware
- synching within your home probably will be faster

con:

- data protection is your "responsibility"

  - both from hardware failures and hacker attacks
- remote availability depends on your home's internet connection and works only if your home is connected to the internet (no availability during power outage)
- probably slower performance if you travel far from your home

I intentionally didn't included cost; it depends on a lot of factors.